# How to filter out try output elements

Tags: r, data-structures, filter, try-catch

With the data structured like below:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  alpha  beta optim_out      
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>         
1   6.4   6.4 <list [5]>     
2   0.4   6.4 <list [5]>     
3   0.4   0.2 <list [5]>     
4   1.6   1.6 <S3: try-error>
5   3.2   0.4 <S3: try-error>
6   0.8   0.8 <list [5]>
```

I need to filter out all `<S3: try-error>` elements which are the output from `base::try()`. How can I state the condition to do this?

I have tried `dplyr::filter(!is.list(optim_out))` and `dplyr::filter((!attr(optim_out, 'class') == 'try-error'))` but neither worked.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example.

Comment: not reproducible yet: `object '.x' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the dataset column is a `list`, we can loop through the column with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   filter(map_lgl(optim_out, ~ class(.x) != "try-error"))
```